# Issue with WebRTC/getUserMedia in iOS 14 Safari and phone sleep/unlock

Tags: webrtc, mobile-safari, getusermedia

I seem to have noticed a regression with getUserMedia in iOS 14 Safari. Here are steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/ on iOS 14 Safari
2. Click "Open camera" and accept camera permissions; you should see local camera video.
3. Click the power button and lock the phone; let the phone go to sleep
4. Unlock/wake the phone; the local camera video is gone.

This does not happen on devices running iOS 13.

My questions are:

1. Can anyone else confirm this on their devices? I have only tested on iPhone 11 so far.
2. Has anyone found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I am having the a similar strange issue with iOS 14.2 and getUserMedia I can only get
`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true })` to work
If I change it to:
`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })`
it will fail.
It's not an issue with code as I tested my project on safari MacOS, chrome for MacOS, linux Firefox.

As a temp fix so I could move on with my life for the moment I did this:

```
const constraints = navigator.userAgent.includes("iPhone") ? {video:true} : {
audio:true,
  video: {
      width: { ideal: 640 },
      height: {ideal: 400 }
      }    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes also here!

I check this behavior in Browserstack with iOS:

- 12.x: ✓
- 13.x: ✓
- 14.x: ✗

Try this:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
 .then(stream => {
   const videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
   console.log(videoTracks[0].enabled);
   document.querySelector('video').srcObject = stream;
 });

// Output
true <-- ?
```

Then if you try again get the camera, but replacing the video track on the previous MediaStream works.

Sometimes if you use video constraints with `facingMode: 'user'` also works, why? I don't know.

**I still can't find a consistent solution.**

Comment: Is this code is for swift ? and How can I add this code in my code ?

Comment: @rohitsankpal this code is for the web, apparently, this only happens in Safari iOS, so I don't know if this behavior exists in a native app, except if you use WKWebView.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.

Comment: I'm using a WKWEbview , I couldn't get  the getUserMedia working , it throws Type Error. Can you help me out some how

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue on iPad pro 2nd generation with iOS 14.7.1 and iPhone 7 iOS 14.6.x. The only solution I found that seems to constantly work is to call `getUserMedia` separated by `audio` and `video` constraints. As an example:

```js
async function getMedia(constraints) {
  let videoStream = null;
  let audioStream = null;

  try {
    videoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
    audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});
    /* use the stream */
  } catch (err) {
    /* handle the error */
  }
}
```

You can replace `{video: true}` or `{audio: true}` with your desired constraints. Then you can either work with the separate `MediaStream` objects or to construct your own `MediaStream` object from the audio and video tracks of your streams.